# Module and Class in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

What are the differences between Module and Class in OCaml.

From my searching, I found this:

> Both provide mechanisms for abstraction and encapsulation, for
>   subtyping (by omitting methods in objects, and omitting ﬁelds in
>   modules), and for inheritance (objects use inherit; modules use
>   include). However, the two systems are not comparable.
>   On the one hand, objects have an advantage: objects are ﬁrst-class
>   values, and modules are not—in other words, modules do not support
>   dynamic lookup. On the other hand, modules have an advantage: modules
>   can contain type deﬁnitions, and objects cannot.

First, I don't understand what does "Modules do not support dynamic lookup" mean. From my part, abstraction and polymorphism do mean parent pointer can refer to a child instance. Is that the "dynamic lookup"? If not, what actually dynamic lookup means?

In practical, when do we choose to use Module and when Class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From a practical perspective dynamic lookup lets you have different objects with the same method without specifying to which class/module it belongs. It helps you when using inheritance.

For example, let's use two data structures: `SingleList` and `DoubleLinkedList`, which, both, inherit from `List` and have the method `pop`. Each class has its own implementation of the method (because of the '*override*').

So, when you want to call it, the lookup of the method is done at runtime (a.k.a. *dynamically*) when you do a `list#pop`.

If you were using modules you would have to use `SingleList.pop list` or `DoubleLinkedList.pop list`.

**EDIT**: As @Majestic12 said, most of the time, OCaml users tend to use modules over classes. Using the second when they need inheritance or instances (check his answer).

I wanted to make the description practical as you seem new to OCaml.

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 13):

The main difference between Module and Class is that you don't instantiate a module.

A module is basically just a "drawer" where you can put types, functions, other modules, etc... It is just here to order your code. This drawer is however really powerful thanks to functors.

A class, on the other hand, exists to be instantiated. They contains variables and methods. You can create an object from a class, and each object contains its own variable and methods (as defined in the class).

In practice, using a module will be a good solution most of the time. A class can be useful when you need inheritance (widgets for example).